# Key detection isn’t always working when changing gravity in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having some odd behavior with a game I am making.  The main idea is that the user will travel down a path and can press space bar to invert the gravity and avoid obstacles.  The problem I am having is that when I press space bar the gravity inverts most of the time, but sometimes it will not work correctly.

I did the key detection in the Update method and changed the gravity in the FixedUpdate method.  I wasn’t sure if it was technically a physics calculation, so I just put it in there.

Here is my code:

```
public class BallMove : MonoBehaviour{
bool jump = false;
float grav = -9.81f;
bool changeGravity = false;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, grav, 0);
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        changeGravity = true;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{

    if ( Input.GetKeyDown("space")  && changeGravity )
    {
        changeGravity = false;
        grav *= -1;
        Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, grav, 0);
    } 
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The [document of GetKeyDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) says

> You need to call this function from the Update function, since the state gets reset each frame.

So it's wrong to detect key in `FixedUpdate`

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (changeGravity)
    {
        changeGravity = false;
        grav *= -1;
        Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, grav, 0);
    } 
}
```